# Check if a date exists in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, html, date, object

I have a php array of date strings and a native html5 date input box.
I have output the date array to a json object to allow use with javascript:

```
<script>
var date_array = <?php echo json_encode($aDates); ?>;
...
```

This gives output like so:

```
var date_array = {
    "2013-12-05": "2013-12-05",
    "2013-12-04": "2013-12-04",
    "2013-12-03": "2013-12-03"
    ...
    };
```

I'm using the html5 native date input box and I want to check that the value a user has chosen exists in the json object. It appears that in (my version of) chrome the format of the date string in the input is `dd/mm/yyyy` so I imagine some date parsing will be necessary.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var date_input = $('input#end_date');
    date_input.change(function(){
        if( jQuery.inArray(date_input.val(), date_array) > -1 ){
            date_input.parent().addClass('has-success');
            date_input.parent().removeClass('has-error');
        } else {
            date_input.parent().addClass('has-error');
            date_input.parent().removeClass('has-success');
        }
    });
```

Which is not working as it should.
Any ideas how to improve?

Comment: The values in `date_array` aren't dates. They are all strings. So you need to make sure `date_input.val()` is in the same format as your strings

Comment: date_array is not an array. use `date_array = ["2013-12-05", "2013-12-04", "2013-12-03"]` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the date input box should return the date as a string in `yyyy-mm-dd` format ([ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.value)). To check whether the date exists in the date_array ***object*** you can simply:

```
var date_str = $("input#end_date").val();
if (typeof date_array[date_str] != "undefined") {
    // exists
} else {
    // does not exist
}
```

Comment: You are right. As @schopy said despite the placeholder the value is in ISO format making it easy to check with the right comparison. Many thanks it now works.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Dates from the strings in the json `new Date("2013-12-05")` and another Date from the user's input and then compare them

Comment: Computationally it seems a waste to create a new array of dates from the strings in the json object when I should just be able compare the strings, should the input be in the right format.

Comment: @harryg The value of the input box is in the same format as the json on my chrome even if the placeholder is mm/dd/yyyy. I just saw guy777's comment and he is right, the json is not an array, that must be it